# How to write and read a single Numpy 2D array to and from a CSV file as a single command in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

Is there a single Python command, one each to

- write a single Numpy 2D array to a CSV file
- read the contents of a CSV file to a single Numpy 2D array

There is `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` functions to do the above, but can this be done in a single line command like in Octave/MATLAB like

```
csvwrite('filename.csv', variable);
variable = csvread('filename.csv');
```

Comment: When you say "one-liner" does that include a function that you already wrote that does all that for you? Because that would be very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [np.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and its counterpart, [np.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), which will

> Save an array to a text file.

and

> Load data from a text file

respectively.

By their arguments they can be used to read and write CSV files:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('fname.csv', variable, delimiter=',') 
variable = np.loadtxt('fname.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Great, with a little tweaking in the arguments, you can use this for the purpose posted in the question: `np.savetxt('fname.csv', variable, delimiter=',')`
`variable = np.loadtxt('fname.csv', delimiter=',')`